# python cgi ajax lag

Tags: python, ajax, cgi

im using a python script to display text to the screen with ajax but it's laggy and sometimes not even working..

here's the python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi, cgitb
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
q = form.getvalue('q')
print "Content-Type: text/html\n" 
print q
```

and the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function show(str){
            var xmlhttp;
            if (str.length == 0){
                document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML = "";
                return;
            }
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else{
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                    document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","../cgi-bin/ajax_test.py?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="show(this.value)" />
    </form>
    <span id="hint"></span>
</body>
```

is it my code's fault? or is it because cgi/python is slow?

Comment: Do you observe any lags when you repeatedly call `ajax_test.py` directly in browser?

Comment: @thg435 I can't tell. It seems to be done right after the page is done loading, but again i can't be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your example works just fine for me on a local OSX apache server, I would suggest that using python CGI as a backend solution to serving ajax calls would be highly inefficient. The very nature of CGI means that every single request has to spawn a process of that python script.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface

> Calling a command generally means the invocation of a newly created
>   process on the server. Starting the process can consume much more time
>   and memory than the actual work of generating the output, especially
>   when the program still needs to be interpreted or compiled. If the
>   command is called often, the resulting workload can quickly overwhelm
>   the web server.
>   The overhead involved in interpretation may be reduced
>   by using compiled CGI programs, such as those in C/C++, rather than
>   using Perl or other scripting languages. The overhead involved in
>   process creation can be reduced by solutions such as FastCGI, or by
>   running the application code entirely within the web server using
>   extension modules such as mod_php.

While it may function just fine locally, with just you doing tests, it will be much more impacted when you make it public facing, with multiple clients connecting.

wsgi (or at least fastcgi) is a far superior approach to old school CGI scripts. You could use mod_wsgi if you are using apache. There is also [uwsgi](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/), [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/), and many other approaches I am sure. Ultimately the idea is that instead of having a stand alone script that is called for every request, you have a persistant process that is running, accepting requests, and executing functions.

These days I think people just use the python CGI module as a learning step to writing server-side web code via python. You may want to consider moving over to a framework.

Answer (score 0):

When using python as cgi, then for each request a new python iterpreter has to be started to handles the request which naturally includes some overhead for the process creation.

As you're sending a new request for each `keyup` event, there can be quite a lot of processes being started in the background. It would probably be better to catch the `change` event instead or only send the request when return is pressed.

Other then that it would be better to use [wsgi](http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) instead of cgi to run your script because that avoids to restart the interpreter on each request.

Comment: Thats a good suggestion about controlling when the ajax request is sent. I would further suggest maybe using a delay (as opposed to return pressed), to where it will only fire after it hasn't changed in N milliseconds. I do that in some of my own GUI code for fields that generate triggers.

Comment: The goal is to use the script to search a sqlite database and show suggestions. Looks like wsgi is the way to go. thank you both for your help.